# Calculate difficult Fourier Transform

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis

I have to calculate a quite difficult Fourier Transform for my class
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty dw\frac{(\varGamma-iw)w^3}{(\varGamma-iw)^2+1}\frac{J_{1}(|wr|)}{|wr|}e^{-iwt}$$
$J_1$ is the normal Bessel function of first order. Please help me.